# how to post data with dbCRUD for nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

The get functionality for dbcrud works fine retrieves information from mysql database. But I am unable to post data i.e. insert data to mysql database. Moreover does dbCRUD have support for put and delete? it gets interpreted as get as far as i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand that this does not fully answer your question, you will have to post the code you are trying for specific answers about why your calls aren't working.

As for your other questions, have you read the documentation? PUT does not seem to be deleted, however a post request to an already existing resource will perform an update. You can see this in the second code block [here](https://github.com/johnroers/dbCRUD#the-quick-pitch).

You can read about deleting [here](https://github.com/johnroers/dbCRUD#to-do).

> Deleting is half-baked at the moment. When you issue a save on any
>   object, if "_destroy" is defined and true in that object, dbCRUD will
>   DELETE it. That's currently the only way to delete, and it works well
>   enough. But clearly some devoted methods are in order.